# Kotlin Flow : How can i get the cache data from subscription in flow when i have new subscriber?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In my use case I have a fragment with a data subscription, which fetch data per 3 seconds automatically. And when the fragment is destroyed, this subscription will be stopped because no subscriber using this data subscription.

However, if I opened a popup dialog fragment from this fragment and the dialog fragment is connected with data subscription. I will get a weird user experience that user might wait up to 3 seconds to see the data. I found out that the first fragment is not on paused and it will treat the first call flag as invalid and delay 3 seconds to emit the new data.

case:

Fragment A -> Dialog Fragment B

- FragmentA : onResume
- FragmentB : onResume

Here is my repository class with a temporary solution using simple flag and while loop. I am using flow, how could i send the last result to the new observer so they dun have to wait up to 3 seconds to receive new data?

Appreciate any advice or comments

DataRepository.kt

```
class DataRepository {
    private val isCalledFirstTime = AtomicBoolean(true)
    private val latestData by lazy {
            flow {
                while (true) {
                    if (hasSubscription()) {
                        try {
                            val response = restService.getData()
                            emit(response)
                            isCalledFirstTime.set(false)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            logger.e(e)
                        }
                    }
                    if (isCalledFirstTime.get()) {
                        delay(200)
                    } else {
                        var count = 0
                        do {
                            delay(200)
                        } while (count++ < (200 / 3000) && !isCalledFirstTime.get())
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    fun observeData() = latestData
}
```

Comment: How are you collecting the `flow` in your fragment?

Comment: i use this `repository.observeData().asLiveData()` in viewModel and then expose it to fragment. If it is not clear, it could update my question including fragment and viewmodeal layer code

Answer (score 1):

Because your latestData is a cold flow you have to convert it to a hot flow like StateFlow or SharedFlow to get the cached value with the same publisher.

To make that, we will use `Flow.shareIn` operator

```
class DataRepository() {
    private val repoScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
    private val latestData by lazy {
            flow {
                // Your code
            }.shareIn(
                repoScope,
                replay = 1,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed()
            )
    }
}
```

- `replay`: How many values do you want to get from cached when starting subscribed.

More information here : [Making cold flows hot using shareIn](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#sharein)

Answer (score 0):

I think your `LiveData` might become inactive, when your view gets into *PAUSED* state.

I'd double check if this is the case, with [LiveData.onInactive()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#oninactive)
Also I wouldn't convert it to `LiveData` I'd go with observing simply the flow:

```
repository.observeData().flowWithLifecycle(this, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    .onEach {
        ...
    }
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope) // or viewLifecycleScope
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your solution does not work in MVVM structure. In fragment, we dun suppose to call repository directly.

Comment: Definitely, this is just an example, I was thinking of writing it more concisely, but you can replace `repository.observeData()`, with `viewModel.flowData()` or what you have in your `VM`

Comment: So you mean i should expose the flow from viewModel without converting it to livedata?

Comment: Yes, I'd try to move towards `flows` and `StateFlows` as much as possible. It seems that `LiveData` is on it's way towards getting deprecated: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow

Comment: Though it might be easier to still use livedatas for databinding, but otherwise I would start using `StateFlow` and `SharedFlow`